# UIAlertView's UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput custom font doesn't work in iOS

Tags: ios, uialertview, uifont

I have to use custom font in `UIAlertView's` `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput` in my iOS App.

My codes that doesn't work.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Create New Folder" message:@"Please enter folder name." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Create", nil];

    alert.tag = 1;
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alert textFieldAtIndex:0].font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyCustomFont" size:15];

    [alert show];
```

How can i use Custom Font in `UIAlertView` textField?

Comment: The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified ,[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)

Comment: I think there might be a slight misunderstanding here. From what I have read of the question they aren't wanting to change the view hierarchy and they aren't wanting to subclass `UIAlertView` all they want to do is change the font to a custom font. Which Apple do accept they have no issue with the user changing the font on a `UIAlertView`.

Comment: Although I would suggest using a custom alert view check out (https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=alternative+to+uialertview&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=6juMU-KgEcqYjAeg8IGgAg#channel=sb&q=uialertbiew+alternative+github&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&safe=active)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot customise the appearance of alert view as it has been made private by apple. 
Please refer subclassing notes in the link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html

Answer (score 1):

In iOS > 7.0, you can not change the appearance of `UIAlertView`, as its view hierarchy is private.

The [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) says:

> The `UIAlertView` class is intended to be used as-is and does not support sub-classing. **The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified**.

So, its not possible to change the font.

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 1):

After iOS 7.x you cannot customize the appearance of alert views, Because its view hierarchy is private.

It is mentioned clearly in [UIAlertView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html):

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not
> support subclasses. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
> **does not be modified**.

it is impossible to change the textField font, buttons text color .. etc.

The only solution is using one of the custom UIAlertView's. just like

> [DTAlertView](https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview)
>
> [SDCAlertView](https://github.com/Scott90/SDCAlertView)